# "New Tor Circuit for this Site" changes all tabs IP addreses

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I am new here so.. I'm having a rough day now, it's Tor the one responsible for this.

So, the issue comes from "New Tor Circuit for this Site" option, it appears to change ALL the tabs IP addresses instead of one I'm in.. What is going on? It's frustating ... Also I updated to the latest version.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could stop posting the same question, sometimes even with a different account, that'd be great. The answer is: (1) stop trying to game a survey, and (2) Tor Browser is working as intended.

Comment: This is my only account here, what you just said is ridiculous.. I'l quote: "* 
But this started happening yesterday ... :[ Now it changes IP's for ALL the tabs, while three days ago, I could run the same link in different tabs with different IP addresses... *"

Comment: [Don't play stupid](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/16263/20069). And you must simply be mistaken about Tor Browser's previous behavior. A properly working Tor Browser does exactly as @canonizing and I have stated, and has done so for years.

Comment: Sorry but that post is not me, I have only this account and don't have any others.. I don't know what is going on then? I was doing surveys and I need more "people" to do it so I was able to run multiple tabs with same link using "New Tor Circuit for this Site" to change the ip.. I don't understand, I click Begin Survey and all of the sudden all the tabs get their IP's assigned to the last ip address.. Does this have something to do with cookies??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circuits are per-site, not per-tab. When you request a new circuit for the site, all of your tabs for that site will use the new circuit as soon as you click a link or a button or do anything else to cause your browser to make an HTTP request to that site.

But as pastly said, please do not use Tor for evil. Besides evil being evil, it also gives Tor a bad reputation.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this issue. I have done the following.

1. I have a reddit.com tab open and a facebook.com tab open.
2. I select "New Tor Circuit for this Site" while on the Reddit tab
3. The Reddit tab reloads and has a new circuit.
4. I click on a link or refresh the Facebook tab and it continues using its original circuit

If I open a second Reddit tab, the two Reddit tabs always use the same circuit. Perhaps this is what you are seeing?

This is by design. "New Tor Circuit **for this Site**" means for *all tabs that are visiting **this Site***.

Comment: What's happening is, I open one TAB and okay, it uses it's own circuit.
I open the same link again, and I click "New TOR Circuit for this Site", thing is it changes the circuit for that tab, but after a minute the other tab also changes it circuit!? Is this some bug in the configuration, if so, how do I reset the configuration to it's default? (I'm on Windows platform)

Comment: No, it's not a bug as pastly said: **"New Tor Circuit for this Site" means for all tabs that are visiting this Site.**. The other tab will use the new circuit for all new connections that it makes, as intended.

Comment: But this started happening yesterday ... :[
Now it changes IP's for ALL the tabs, while three days ago, I could run the same link in different tabs with different IP addresses...